# Let $V$ be a real normed finite dimensional vector space. Is it true that $A \subseteq V$ compact iff $A$ is closed and bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

> Let $V$ be a real normed finite dimensional vector space. Is it true
>   that $A \subseteq V$ compact iff $A$ is closed and bounded?

I know the result is true if the vector space is $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself. To prove this, I should prove that isomorphisms map bounded sets to bounded sets and closed sets to closed sets, but for some reason, this is hard for me.

Is a stronger statement true? I.e., do linear isomorphisms preserve compactness?

Comment: Every real normed finite dimensional space is isometric to $\mathbb{R}^n$ so the answer is yes.

Comment: Do isomorphisms preserve compactness then? How would I prove this?

Comment: Linear maps on finite dimensional space are continuous (so they automatically preserve compactness and closeness) and they preserve being bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All linear transformations on a finite dimensional space are continuous, and any finite dimensional space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I see that this is sufficient to prove. Give me a couple of minuts to see that I can find a proof that all such linear transformations are continuous.

Answer (score 1):

On a finite-dimensional real vector space, all norms are equivalent. So, if your statement is true for the usual norm, it is true for *every* norm.